# How to change navigationBarTitle when there is a back button

Tags: swift, swiftui

I study SwiftUI.

Trying out of this:

[image]

Do it:

[image]

How to add the title correctly in this case?

code:

```
struct CalculatorView: View {
 
    var body: some View {

        .navigationBarTitle("Оформить займ")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: CustomBackButton {
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    })
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set your title, you can also specify a displayMode:

```
.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
```